# Wrong error while uploading bigger files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file that is bigger then the limit by my error is not "Exceeded filesize limit.", My code look like this:

**js**

```
self.on('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var prompt;
    var org = e.originalEvent;
    var files = org.dataTransfer.files || org.target.files;
    var token = terminal.token();
    if (!token) {
        return;
    }
    if (files.length) {
        files = [].slice.call(files);
        (function upload() {
            var file = files.shift();
            function uploadFile() {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', file);
                formData.append('token', token);
                formData.append('path', leash.cwd);
                animation = true;
                var anim = ['/', '-', '\\', '|'], i = 0, delay = 400;
                var timer;
                (function animation() {
                    terminal.set_prompt(anim[i++]);
                    if (i > anim.length-1) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    timer = setTimeout(animation, delay);
                })();
                function finish() {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    terminal.set_prompt(prompt);
                    animation = false;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'lib/upload.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response) {
                        finish();
                        if (response.error) {
                            terminal.error(response.error);
                        } else {
                            terminal.echo('File "' + file.name + '" ' +
                                          'uploaded.');
                        }
                        upload();
                    },
                    error: function(jxhr, error, status) {
                        terminal.error(jxhr.statusText);
                        finish();
                    },
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                });
            }
            if (file) {
                prompt = terminal.get_prompt();
                var fname = leash.cwd + '/' + file.name;
                leash.service.file_exists(fname)(function(err, exists) {
                    if (exists) {
                        var msg = 'File "' + file.name + '" exists do you'+
                            ' want to overwrite (Y/N)? ';
                        terminal.push(function(yesno) {
                            if (yesno.match(/^y$/i)) {
                                // upload
                                terminal.pop();
                                uploadFile();
                            } else if (yesno.match(/^n$/i)) {
                                terminal.pop();
                                upload();
                            }
                        }, {
                            prompt: msg
                        });
                    } else {
                        uploadFile();
                    }
                });
            }
        })();
    }
}).on('dragover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).on('dragenter', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

and **php**:

```
require('Service.php');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$service = new Service('config.json', preg_replace("/\/[^\/]+$/", "", getcwd()));

if (isset($_POST['token']) && isset($_POST['path'])) {
    if ($service->valid_token($_POST['token'])) {
        if (!isset($_FILES['file'])) {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => 'No File'));
            exit();
        }
        $fname = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

        switch ($_FILES['file']['error']) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                $full_name = $_POST['path'] . '/' . $fname;
                if (file_exists($full_name) && !is_writable($full_name)) {
                    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'File "'.$fname.'" is not writable'));
                } else {
                    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                                            $full_name)) {
                        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Can\'t save file.'));
                    } else {
                        echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
                    }
                }
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                echo json_encode(array('error' => 'File not sent.'));
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Exceeded filesize limit.'));
                break;
            default:
                echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Unknown errors.'));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Invalid Token'));
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Wrong request'));
}
```

when I upload file that is bigger then the limit I got error "Wrong request" anybody know why? If file is smaller the file is uploading correctly.

**UPDATE**: If I echo $_POST and $_FILES arrays they are empty:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'error' => 'Wrong request',
    'POST' => $_POST,
    'FILE' => $_FILES
));
```

Comment: Pls show your html (form).

Comment: @TareqMahmood  I don't have a form it's drag and drop upload.

Comment: what is `leash` object? how does it form?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you can find whole source code here https://github.com/jcubic/leash/blob/devel/leash-src.js